# vector addition in OPENCL /C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl

I hope you are well, I have a problem with an opencl program, I execute the following program of the vector addition

```
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2APIS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
#include <CL/cl.h>

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)
 
int main(void) {
    // Create the two input vectors
    int i;
    const int LIST_SIZE = 10;
    int *A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    int *B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        A[i] = i;
        B[i] = LIST_SIZE - i;
    }
 
    // Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    size_t source_size;
 
    fp = fopen("vector_add_kernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread( source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose( fp );
 
    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;   
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, 
            &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
 
    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);
 
    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(context, device_id, 0, &ret);
 
    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector 
    cl_mem a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem b_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem c_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
 
    // Copy the lists A and B to their respective memory buffers
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, b_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);
 
    // Create a program from the kernel source
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, 
            (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);
 
    // Build the program
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 
    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vector_add", &ret);
 
    // Set the arguments of the kernel
 
   ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&a_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&b_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&c_mem_obj);
 
    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t global_item_size = LIST_SIZE; // Process the entire lists
    size_t local_item_size = 64; // Divide work items into groups of 64
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
            &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
 
    // Read the memory buffer C on the device to the local variable C
    int *C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, c_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0, 
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), C, 0, NULL, NULL);
 
    // Display the result to the screen
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", A[i], B[i], C[i]);
 
    // Clean up
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(a_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(b_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(c_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    return 0;
}
```

With the following kernel:

```
__kernel void vector_add(__global int *A, __global int *B, __global int *C) {
    
    // Get the index of the current element
    int i = get_global_id(0);

    // Do the operation
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    printf("calcule effectué");
}
```

While running a C program, I'm getting the following result and I can't seem to figure out why

0 + 10 = 714121520

1 + 9 = 21995

2 + 8 = 0

3 + 7 = 0

4 + 6 = 1852255608

5 + 5 = 1768697717

6 + 4 = 1932425826

7 + 3 = 3223151

8 + 2 = 1919885413

9 + 1 = 1953459744

I don't know what is the problem, please any help !!!!

Comment: You should check the error code of functions. They are meant to warn you when errors occurs. If you do not care about them, then silent errors happen and you get invalid data like this.

Comment: How can I find this errors , because the compilation doesn't give me any errors

Comment: The compiler check the syntax of your program or (partially) the semantics but it tells you nothing about the validity of your program at runtime. A division by zero for example can only be detected at runtime. See the error section of the OpenCL function documentation. For example: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties.html. More generally, *absence of evidence is not evidence of absence*.

Answer (score 0):

I also get wrong results, and moreover the results are random for each execution. This means that the values in the `C` array are never overwritten, and the uninitialized, random values in that allocated memory location are printed.

First step to debug is to print `ret` and see where things go wrong:

- After `clGetDeviceIDs` I got error -1 (device not found). `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL` cleared that; then the selected device was my Nvidia GPU.
- After `clCreateProgramWithSource` I got error -6 (out of host memory). To fix this, use `cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&source_str, NULL, &ret);`.
- After `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` I got error -54 (invalid workgroup size). To fix this, make `global_item_size` a multiple of `local_item_size`: `size_t global_item_size = ((LIST_SIZE+local_item_size-1)/local_item_size)*local_item_size;`. Since your intended global size (or rather size of allocated buffers) is not a multiple if the workgroup size, you should also put a guard clause `if(i>=10) return;` in the kernel; otherwise the kernel may write values in undefined memory space which can cause crashes.

Then, everything works as intended. Here is the entire fixed code:

```c
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2APIS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <CL/cl.h>

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)

int main(void) {
    // Create the two input vectors
    int i;
    const int LIST_SIZE = 10;
    int* A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    int* B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    int* C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        A[i] = i;
        B[i] = LIST_SIZE - i;
        C[i] = 0;
    }

    // Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
    size_t source_size;

    const char* source_str =
        "__kernel void vector_add(__global int *A, __global int *B, __global int *C) {\n"
        "    int i = get_global_id(0);\n"
        "    if(i>=10) return;\n"
        "    C[i] = A[i]+B[i];\n"
        "}"
    ;

    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1,
        &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);
    std::cout << "context " << ret << std::endl;

    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);
    std::cout << "queue " << ret << std::endl;

    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector 
    cl_mem a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem b_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem c_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    std::cout << "buffer " << ret << std::endl;

    // Copy the lists A and B to their respective memory buffers
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, b_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::cout << "write " << ret << std::endl;

    // Create a program from the kernel source
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&source_str, NULL, &ret);
    //cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);
    std::cout << "program " << ret << std::endl;

    // Build the program
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vector_add", &ret);
    std::cout << "kernel " << ret << std::endl;

    // Set the arguments of the kernel

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&a_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&b_mem_obj);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&c_mem_obj);
    std::cout << "args " << ret << std::endl;

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t local_item_size = 64; // Divide work items into groups of 64
    size_t global_item_size = ((LIST_SIZE+local_item_size-1)/local_item_size)*local_item_size; // make global range a multiple of local range
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::cout << "run " << ret << std::endl;
    clFinish(command_queue);

    // Read the memory buffer C on the device to the local variable C
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, c_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
        LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), C, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::cout << "read " << ret << std::endl;

    // Display the result to the screen
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", A[i], B[i], C[i]);

    // Clean up
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(a_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(b_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(c_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Debugging that was quite a hassle. Do yourself a favor and use this [OpenCL-Wrapper](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper) with C++. This eliminates all the code overhead and the countless possibilities for errors that come with it.